# Error: JIRA python API : "errors":{"customfield_10800":"The Team must be a string"}}

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am using JIRA python api to update JIRA

I need to update customfield_10800 field.

below is the code i used

```
updatedict = {
     "customfield_10800": 
     { "id": "485", 
        "title": "Facilities IT", "isShared": True
     }
    } 
   self.jira = self.LogInJira() 
   issue = self.jira.issue(jiraid) 
   issue.update(fields=updatedict) 
   self.jira.transition_issue(jiraid, transition=jid)
```

I am getting the following error

response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10800":"The Team must be a string"}}

can you help to solve

Comment: What kind of field is `customfield_10800`? You probably need something like `{"customfield_10800": "Facilities IT"}`

Comment: Thank you ..it worked i passed only ID {"customfield_10800": "485"}